# How to enable the whole frame of axis when doing 3-d plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, 3d, matplotlib

I have been trying to add additional axis ticks to the top of the 3-d axis, such that a 'cube' of axis is showed, instead of only 3 sides as default does, but without success.
Does anyone have an idea of how to do that?

And another minor thing is that how to set the color of the grid?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d',frame_on=True)  # first try, nothing happened

ax.plot([1,], [1,], [1,], marker='o')

ax_grid_color = (0.9, 0.1, 0.1, 1.0)
ax.grid(color=ax_grid_color)   # doesn't work

ax_pane_color = (1, 1, 1, 1.0)
ax.w_xaxis.set_pane_color(ax_pane_color)
ax.w_yaxis.set_pane_color(ax_pane_color)
ax.w_zaxis.set_pane_color(ax_pane_color)
ax.w_xaxis.set_ticks_position('both')  # 2nd try

plt.show()
```

[image]